# LinkFilename - display text from other field

Tags: list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part, hyperlink

I have document library with column `LinkFilename` which renders link to document, where text is the name of the file. Is it possible to modify column is such way, that it will still render link to document but the text will be coming from another field (eg. `MyTitle`)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, when you select a field and go to further properties [as shown in the below article], you can choose which field should make the link and which to appear as text... These options are available when the field is supposed to work as HyperLink

[Data View Web Part, The Basics - Add a Hyperlink](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/data-view-web-part-the-basics-add-a-hyperlink.aspx)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It could be accomplished by [customizing the Rendering of a Field on a List View using XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Below is described solution using SharePoint Designer (SPD).

### Solution

In SharePoint Designer (SPD) open view page (AllItems.aspx) in Designer Mode. Select list item in List View that have to be customized (Name column) and then click *Customize Item* as shown on picture below
[image]

Switch to *Code Mode* and find template code for rendering `LinkFilename` generated by SPD

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='LinkFilename']" name="LinkFilenameNoMenu.LinkFilename" mode="Computed_LinkFilename_body" ddwrt:tag="a" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" ddwrt:ghost="show">
...
</xsl:template>
```

Inside template **replace** the line for rendering FileLeafRef value:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef.Name" />
```

with the following one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@MyTitle" />
```

> Note:
>   Custom field with internal name MyTitle is used here

After you save your changes your page should look like this one:
[image]

Comment: Only works when Mytitle is also in the view, else its not a part of thisNode.